# How to use 'having'?

Tags: word-usage

How to translate the following sentence to German. Having one good friend is better than having thousand bad friends. Please help.

Comment: Please read the above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would translate it as:

> Einen guten Freund **zu haben** ist besser als tausend schlechte (Freunde zu haben).

The latter part (the part I put in parentheses) doesn't have to be repeated, in my opinion. I wouldn't repeat it in English either.

Comment: Greetings from google translate ;)

Comment: @äöü: Could be that Google can translate it. I don't fully trust it, though. Sometimes, it still throws out weird constructs, even if it has become much better than a few years ago.